# pascal формула 123

Tags: pascal

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как записать эту формулу в паскале ?

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от того, что у вас означает "пэ житое" и "ку итое".

Может быть это  - элементы массива `i*sin(P[j])`, а может, нужно функцией их получать `i*sin(P(j))`

Comment: Всё же подозреваю, что это вариант с массивами — иначе было бы что-то вроде `P(i)`

Comment: @4500zenja надо знать постановку задачи